# Disappearing Cocoa Titlebar in OSX 10.10

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I'm working on an app that needs to create windows programmatically (GUI functionality for a scripting language), and all versions more recent than OSX v10.10 seem to not draw the title bar. Here's the most bare-bones code calling my class that I could get to create the problem:

`uint32_t hmslOpenWindow(const char* title, short x, short y, short w, short h) {
  NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h);
  NSString *windowTitle = [NSString stringWithCString:title encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  NSWindow* hmslWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                           styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
                                           backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                           defer:YES];
  hmslWindow.title = windowTitle;
  [hmslWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:hmslWindow];
  [hmslWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.4 blue:0.1 alpha:0.5]];
  mainWindow = hmslWindow;
  return (uint32_t)hmslWindow.windowNumber;
}`

The titlebar still works (clicking where the close button *should* be closes the window), and the correct title appears in the menu under the Window heading, but nothing shows up.

Here's what the window looks like. I'm at a total loss, so any help helps.

[image]

UPDATE: When I add `[[hmslWindow.contentView superview] addSubview:titleBarView];` everything looks as planned, but there's an warning `NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview: <NSView: 0x4344c0>.`

Comment: Is the host process running the run loop of its main thread? Indeed, is there an application object (have you called `+sharedApplication` on `NSApplication` or a subclass) and is it running its event loop? Cocoa isn't very amenable to being embedded in other programs if it doesn't basically get to control the main thread.

Comment: Actually, this particular function is running on a different thread—the scripting language interpreter's thread. But there is an application object running the event loop, and normal drawing operations and interactivity works just fine. This is just a bare-bones example of the broken title bar.